# Logout : MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 233

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using multi auth for Laravel ...

This is my lougout function for users

LoginController

```
public function logout()
{
    Auth::guard('web')->logout();
    return redirect('/');
}
```

AdminloginController

```
public function logout()
{
    Auth::guard('web')->logout();
    return redirect('/');
}
```

This is my route

```
Route::get('/enseignant/logout', 'Auth\LoginController@Elogout')->name('enseignant.logout');
```

Route::get('/administration/logout', 'Auth\AdminloginController@logout')->name('admin.logout');

All the methods in the view

```
 <a href="{{ route('admin.logout') }}" class="btn btn-default btn-flat"
   onclick="event.preventDefault();
   document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
   Logout
 </a>

 <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('admin.logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
 {{ csrf_field() }}
 </form>
```

The function works fine but when I click the button I get this error :

> MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 233

Comment: what's `RouteCollection.php line 233`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your route accepts only `GET` method, but in the form, you specified using `POST`. I think this is the source of the problem. The error message also indicates that.

It's recommended to use POST for logout, as you did. So, just by changing the route in question to...

```
Route::post(...);
```

... should fix the error.